# How can we restrict users from not accessing an application without Okta plugin?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, okta, multi-factor-authentication

I have an application integrated with Okta Secure web authentication (SWA) and MFA as additional layer of protection. Users can bypass this mechanism by accessing the URL directly in browser. Is there a way to restrict this from happening ?
This question ideally to be asked in product forum but I see a similar question with no proper solution.

Comment: But they need to provide correct username and password to log into the application. What's the difference if they bookmark your App URL and open it in their browser directly?

Comment: Providing the right set of credentials are fine but they skip MFA by accessing the URL directly or through bookmark. My need is to enforce MFA at all cases for users who have elevated access.

Comment: Well, I don't believe you can achieve that w/o having some sorta reverse proxy in front of your application to enforce authentication with Okta. They have OAG virtual appliance, which can do that for you. Or you can choose any other ways of enforcing the same, maybe with `nginx` integrated with Okta